# is it safe to use allow_mixed_block_sizes = 1 in LVM when using ext4 with 4k blocks on LVs?

Tags: lvm

i have Physical Volumes with different blocksizes:

```
blockdev -v --getss --getpbsz --getbsz /dev/md1                                                                                      
get logical block (sector) size: 512
get physical block (sector) size: 4096
get blocksize: 4096

blockdev -v --getss --getpbsz --getbsz /dev/md3                                                                                      
get logical block (sector) size: 4096
get physical block (sector) size: 4096
get blocksize: 4096
```

When trying to extend the existing Volume Group i got the error message:

`Devices have inconsistent logical block sizes (512 and 4096).`

`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` has the option `allow_mixed_block_sizes`, i set to 1 and it allowed me to extend the Volume Group with the new Physical Volume.

I did some testing, created a LV using /dev/md1 as PV, mkfs.ext4 (default 4K blocksize), copied some data to it and used pvmove to move the extends to /dev/md3.

`unmount` and `mount` again showed no problems, no errors when using `pvs`, the data seems OK. (also tested it the other way around, creating the LV using /dev/md3 and moving it to /dev/md1, no problems.)

May my tests be insufficient, e.g. because of read-cache?

I read this thread:
https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2019-February/msg00018.html

some replies say that it is dangerous to mix blocksizes, another one said the problem is because the OP used 1k blocksizes:
https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2019-February/025033.html

I also found another thread, where someone was able to reproduce the data corruption problem, but only when using ext4 with 1k blocks:
https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2019-March/025049.html

So can i conclude from this, that it is safe to mix blocksizes on the same LV when using ext4 with 4k blocks?